# How to solve $\int\frac{x ^ 4 + x ^ 2 + 1}{2(1 + x ^ 2)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have tried factorisation, substitution but didn't work out. I have clipped my solution.

[image: solution-]

Comment: You made the mistake $\frac{ab-c}{a} \neq b-c$

Comment: @NinadMunshi  thnx for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

$$
\displaystyle
\int \dfrac{x^4+x^2+1}{2(1+x^2)} \, dx
= \int \dfrac{(x^4+2x^2+1)-x^2}{2(1+x^2)} \, dx
= \int \dfrac{(x^2+1)^2-x^2}{2(1+x^2)} \, dx
$$

Then the given integral is composed of three terms,

$$
\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^2+1}{2} \, dx
 + \displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{2 (x^2 + 1)}dx - \displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{2}dx
$$

I think you can pick up from here.

BHP

Comment: Thnks for solution , I got the answer 1/2(x³/3+arctan(x)) or X³/6+1/2(arctan(x)).

Comment: Don't forget the C!

Comment: ohh! thnx for correcting

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{2(1+x^2)}dx=\int\frac{x^4+x^2}{2(1+x^2)}dx+\int\frac{1}{2(1+x^2)}dx\\
&=\int\frac{x^2(x^2+1)}{2(1+x^2)}dx+\int\frac{1}{2(1+x^2)}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int x^2dx+\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{2}\arctan x+C.
\end{align}